# Does the Riemann curvature tensor have any visual intuition when its inputs are vectors and not vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curvature

I’ve seen the derivation of the Riemann curvature tensor via the vector R(u,v)w, which essentially gives the rate of change in w as it is parallel transported around the loop defined by u and v as the area of the loop shrinks to zero. This makes sense when u and v are vector fields, as the loop is defined by the flows of u and v (and their Lie bracket to close the curve).

This dependence on the fact that u and v be vector fields reflects itself in the resulting expression for R(u,v)w as the commutator of covariant derivatives (with the Lie bracket term to close the loop) because that construction uses covariant derivatives, so the vector must exist at many different points in space, and thus be a field.

But then I see that this operator R is tensorial in its arguments,  so the same value R(u,v)w can be written by contracting indices with the components of the Riemann tensor. But this way of writing it doesn’t make use of the values of u,v,w at any point other than the one you evaluate it at. So why should the definition of R(u,v)w at a point p need u,v,w to be vector fields, and not just vectors at p?

It seems like we’re requiring u,v,w to be vector fields when we don’t need anything besides their values at p anyway.

Edit: At this point my best bet is apparently to exponentiate a u,v parallelogram in the tangent space. I understand what it means to exponentiate a vector into a geodesic, but I don’t understand exactly what it means to exponentiate a parallelogram in the tangent space...

Comment: Just take (shrinking) parallelograms in the tangent space and exponentiate.

Comment: By exponentiating, do you mean constructing the flows to be the geodesics whose initial data is defined by the tangent vectors u,v?

Comment: The Riemann tensor, by definition, measures the non-commutativity of the second covariant derivatives, and the covariant derivative is not tensorial. But geometry is magic, and the Riemann curvature tensor is... A tensor. So it is tensorial. But we do not have any general expression for it besides the one with covariant derivatives, unless we consider some specific Riemannian manifold. For example, for a manifold with constant curvature $\kappa$, $R(u,v,w,t) = \kappa \left(g(u,w)g(v,t) - g(u,t)g(v,w) \right)$ is such an expression.

Comment: This isn't a flow (without extra work), because for a flow you need a vector field. But a geodesic is determined (as long as it exists) just by an initial tangent vector. It is the solution of a second-order differential equation, whereas flows are solutions of first-order differential equations.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that as I was writing “flow”... What I really meant was curve, as that’s all that’s needed (we’re just parallel transporting along it, after all), and while with a field we could just use the flow curve given by the vector field, here with the single tangent vector we can just substitute the flow with the associated geodesic curve. Is that what you’re saying?

Comment: Yes. And, doing Riemannian geometry, geodesics are more natural than the flow of a random vector field, anyhow. I should add that (perhaps up to sign) $R_p(v,w,v,w)$ gives you the Gaussian curvature at $p$ of the *surface* you get by exponentiating the $2$-plane spanned by $v,w$. A fact not sufficiently known.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just a quick question: What happens if the geodesic curves here don’t close? How do we measure this? I know we use the Lie bracket when we’re dealing with commutativity of flow curves, but what’s the analog of that Lie bracket term here?

Comment: No, I explicitly said to exponentiate the parallelogram in the tangent plane. You’re still stuck with the non-commuting flows picture :)

Comment: I’m a little confused... I can’t see how we can simultaneously demand that the curves forming the sides of the parallelogram are the geodesics with initial values u,v, and also that the parallelogram is closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120668/discussion-between-excitonfield-and-ted-shifrin).